# Create a copy of parcel object

Tags: android, parcelable

I am using the parcel object to pass the value from one process to another. I want to create a clone of the parcel object but I am not able to use clone() method If anyone knows how to create the copy of parcel please provide the solution.

Answer (score 18):

The suggested solution is incomplete and will not work.

Here's a working solution:

(I have an object called message of type MessageDescriptor which I want to clone)

```
Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
message.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
parcel.setDataPosition(0);
MessageDescriptor messageToBeSent = MessageDescriptor.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
parcel.recycle();
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your object implements the `Parcelable` interface, you should be able to do the following:

```
SomethingParcelable myObject = new SomethingParcelable();

Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
myObject.writeToParcel(p, 0);

//must be called after unmarshalling your data.
p.setDataPosition(0);

SomethingParcelable myClonedObject = SomethingParcelable.CREATOR.createFromParcel(p);
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to create a copy without accessing object specific CREATOR use following generic method.

```
 public <T extends Parcelable> T deepClone(T objectToClone) {
    Parcel parcel = null;
    try {   
        parcel = Parcel.obtain();
        parcel.writeParcelable(objectToClone, 0);
        parcel.setDataPosition(0);
        return parcel.readParcelable(objectToClone.getClass().getClassLoader());
    } finally {
        if (parcel != null) {
            parcel.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also useful for copy constructors.

```
/**
 * Copy request passed in.
 *
 * @param request Request To clone, null is accepted, just creates a blank object
 */
public RealTimeJourneyPlanRequest(@Nullable RealTimeJourneyPlanRequest request) {
    if(request == null) return;
    // Only copy if the request past in is not null
    // Use the Parcel as its does deep cloning for us.
    final Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
    request.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
    parcel.setDataPosition(0);
    // Copy into this object
    readFromParcel(parcel);
    // Clean parcel back into object pool
    parcel.recycle();
}
```