# how to clone a Parcel object

Tags: android, clone, parcelable, cloneable, parcel

I want to clone a Parcel object (not parcelable).

I can't use clone() method since it is protected. I also can't call it using reflection since Parcel class doesn't implement 'clonable'

I tried to perform the solution of issue:
[Create a copy of parcel object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467761/create-a-copy-of-parcel-object)
but it does not apply for Parcel type itself - and the reason for that is that 'writeToParcel' is not defined for Parcel type itself. So for the object 'Parcel a',  a.writeToParcel(parcel, 0) won't compile.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Parcel.appendFrom()`

This is more efficient than marshalling and unmarshalling and it won't lose any data about object references or `FileDescriptor`s in the parcel.

Source: Overheard Android framework developer talking about this, and decided to update the Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by marshalling/unmarshalling

```
byte[] rawData = original.marshall();
Parcel clone = Parcel.obtain();
clone.unmarshall(rawData, 0, rawData.length);
clone.setDataPosition(original.dataPosition());
```

It doesn't work for all Parcels though. I think it fails on Parcels with an active object, but I haven't tested to make sure.

Comment: Down-voting because it's an incomplete solution, and not really performant. Parcel#appendFrom is the way to go.